# fatal error: google/protobuf/port_def.inc: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, grpc, protoc

i am on ubuntu and i am using libprotoc version 3.15.8 when i run cmake command it successfully done but when i run `make -j` it's throwing error:

```
.
.
.
[  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ConfigServiceCore.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /home/bugs/workspace/ReactVision/rv_utils/ConfigService/configservicecore.h:3,
                 from /home/bugs/workspace/ReactVision/rv_utils/ConfigService/main.cpp:3:
/home/bugs/workspace/ReactVision/rv_utils/ConfigService/config_vals.pb.h:10:10: fatal error: google/protobuf/port_def.inc: No such file or directory
   10 | #include <google/protobuf/port_def.inc>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ConfigServiceCore.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/ConfigServiceCore.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:159: CMakeFiles/ConfigServiceCore.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

Comment: The first thing to check is whether this file exists anywhere on your system.

Comment: what is the origin of the `config_vals.pb.h`? Did you create it as a part of build process or not? How do you compile proto files? what is the vision of a `protoc` used to create `config_vals.pb.h`?

Comment: ```protoc --cpp_out=. config_vals.proto``` version ```libprotoc 3.15.8```

Comment: ```config_vals.pb.h``` is present in working dir...

Comment: The file that ostensibly doe not exist is `google/protobuf/port_def.inc`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, when I got this error, the project's structure was:

```
project
|
|-CMakeLists.txt
|-main.cpp
|-proto
  |
  |
  |--CMakeLists.txt
  |--message.proto
```

To solve it, I had add to add the "proto" module in the main project's CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(proto)
```

Also, you need to add in **both** CMake's these lines:

```
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
include_directories(${protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Also, try to look for a variable named something like `protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR`; there are no guarantees for it's name (`Protobuf_***` or `protobuf_***`).

Comment: wow thank you so much, you just save me